# Why is pip not working even though its in command line and using -m?

Tags: python

I am trying to code a bot for discord and I need to run `python -m pip install youtube_dl`, but whenever I do, I always receive a syntax error on the pip part. I am running it in command line, and I'm fairly certain I set the path to wher python is installed, but it's still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: what if you just run `pip install youtube_dl` without `python -m`

Comment: In order to get an answer you need to provide every thing you have done so far, plus the errors you are getting, also it is worth mentioning which versions of each software (including OS) you are using.

Comment: Please share the error message!

Comment: @jorijnsmit pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @d_kennetz That still didn't fix it, even when run as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

try running `pip install youtube_dl` as admin

Comment: It resulted in the error "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." It might be a problem with the path, I'll check again.

Comment: I tried again and I set the path to where pip is installed, still didn't work. It might be an issue with the path not working properly. Would it fix it if I uninstalled python and reinstalled it?

Comment: You could do that.  Make sure you install the correct version of Python (2 or 3) and, when installing, make sure to click the "Add Python to Environment Path" box.  You may need to go through custom installation for this; I don't remember.

Comment: To check the python version, run "[command you usually use to run python scripts] -V."  Make sure the "V" is capital.  The bracketed comment should be replaced with "python," "py" or "python3" depending on how you use python.

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you!

Comment: After a bit of work I made it to the error `py -m pip install syntax error` with an arrow under the word pip. I have verified that pip is installed, and I no longer get the `pip is not recognized` error.

Comment: what OS are you working on? Are you able to install other python packages? you can test this by installing numpy

Comment: if you are working in environments like conda/anaconda, mention that too

Comment: by the way, it seems like youtube_dl installation might be a drawn out process; if what I recommended doesn't work, the next step would be going through the instructions at [this](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#faq) link